# Stacked Bar Chart having upper limit line using jfreechart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I'm trying to generate a Stacked Bar Chart having an upper limit for each and every category. The upper limit varies for each and every category and is indicated by a horizontal line.

I was able to generate the stacked bar chart but got struck with horizontal line for indicating upper limit.

Here is the sample chart.

[image: Sample Stacked Bar Chart]

Here is my code for generating stacked bar chart

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItem;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItemCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SubCategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryMarker;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.ValueMarker;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GroupedStackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.KeyToGroupMap;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.GradientPaintTransformType;
import org.jfree.ui.Layer;
import org.jfree.ui.StandardGradientPaintTransformer;

public class StackedBarServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("image/png");

        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        int width = 800;
        int height = 350;
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(outputStream, chart, width, height);

    }
      private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
            DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Jan 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (US)", "Feb 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (US)", "Mar 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Apr 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (US)", "May 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (US)", "Jun 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Jul 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (US)", "Aug 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (US)", "Sep 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Oct 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (US)", "Nov 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (US)", "Dec 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Bab 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (US)", "Lal 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (US)", "Sha 04");

            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (UK)", "Jan 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (UK)", "Feb 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (UK)", "Mar 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (UK)", "Apr 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (UK)", "May 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (UK)", "Jun 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (UK)", "Jul 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (UK)", "Aug 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (UK)", "Sep 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (UK)", "Oct 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (UK)", "Nov 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (UK)", "Dec 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (UK)", "Bab 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (UK)", "Lal 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (UK)", "Sha 04");

            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (IND)", "Jan 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (IND)", "Feb 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (IND)", "Mar 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (IND)", "Apr 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (IND)", "May 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (IND)", "Jun 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (IND)", "Jul 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (IND)", "Aug 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (IND)", "Sep 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (IND)", "Oct 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (IND)", "Nov 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (IND)", "Dec 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (IND)", "Bab 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (IND)", "Lal 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (IND)", "Sha 04");

            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Jan 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Feb 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Mar 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Apr 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "May 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Jun 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Jul 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Aug 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Sep 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Oct 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Nov 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Dec 04");
            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Bab 04");
            result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Lal 04");
            result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (EUROPE)", "Sha 04");

            return result;
        }

        private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

            final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                "Stacked Bar",  // chart title
                "Category",                  // domain axis label
                "Value",                     // range axis label
                dataset,                     // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,    // the plot orientation
                true,                        // legend
                true,                        // tooltips
                false                        // urls
            );

            GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
            KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (US)", "G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Europe)", "G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Asia)", "G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Middle East)", "G1");

            renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map); 

            renderer.setItemMargin(0.0);
            Paint p1 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x22, 0x22, 0xFF), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x88, 0x88, 0xFF)
            );
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, p1);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(4, p1);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(8, p1);

            Paint p2 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x22, 0xFF, 0x22), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x88, 0xFF, 0x88)
            );
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, p2); 
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(5, p2); 
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(9, p2); 

            Paint p3 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0x22, 0x22), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0x88, 0x88)
            );
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, p3);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(6, p3);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(10, p3);

            Paint p4 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x22), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x88)
            );
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, p4);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(7, p4);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(11, p4);
            renderer.setGradientPaintTransformer(
                new StandardGradientPaintTransformer(GradientPaintTransformType.HORIZONTAL)
            );

            SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Product");
            domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.15);

            CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
            plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
            plot.setRenderer(renderer);
            plot.setFixedLegendItems(createLegendItems());

            /*
             * This is used to draw a vertical line
             */
    /*        Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(2.0f);
            ValueMarker marker = new ValueMarker(100);  // position is the value on the axis
            marker.setPaint(Color.black);
            marker.setStroke(stroke);

            CategoryPlot plot1 = chart.getCategoryPlot();
            plot1.addRangeMarker(marker,Layer.FOREGROUND); */

            return chart;

        }

        private LegendItemCollection createLegendItems() {
            LegendItemCollection result = new LegendItemCollection();
            LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem("US", new Color(0x22, 0x22, 0xFF));
            LegendItem item2 = new LegendItem("Europe", new Color(0x22, 0xFF, 0x22));
            LegendItem item3 = new LegendItem("Asia", new Color(0xFF, 0x22, 0x22));
            LegendItem item4 = new LegendItem("Middle East", new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x22));
            result.add(item1);
            result.add(item2);
            result.add(item3);
            result.add(item4);
            return result;
        }
}
```

When I used addRangeMarker, it gives me a continuous horizontal line. But in my case, I need multiple horizonatal lines for each and every category seperately.

Here is the sample image with addRangeMarker.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any code it's difficulte to say. But i think there is a call to addRangeMarker on your CategoryPlot object

Comment: Thank JEY for your response. I've edited my question and added the code. I used addRangeMarker already, it gives a continuous horizontal line. But in my case I need different upper limits for different categories. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a second dataset containing the values that you want to display with the horizontal black lines.  Add that dataset to your plot along with a [`LevelRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LevelRenderer.html).