# How to draw different limit lines for different domain in JFreechart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

We are using ValueMarker to draw limit lines on the chart (line 1 and 2). How can we draw something like line 3?

[image]

I found following ways which are close to what I want but if there is better way to draw this, I would like to use that -

1. Creating seperate plot for drawing the line 3.
2. Using Level Renderer to draw something like mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382457/stacked-bar-chart-having-upper-limit-line-using-jfreechart).

Comment: Also consider [`XYStepRenderer`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjfreechart%5D+XYStepRenderer); note that a plot may have more than one renderer.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks. XYStepRenderer worked perfectly for my use-case.